# output of one query as a table to select the values from in next query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a Question output of my query as a table to select the values from in my next query please suggest your views.

example with DB tables I am using:

First Query:

```
WITH TABLE1
AS (SELECT COT.DESCRIPTION
  FROM CONFIGURABLEOBJECTTYPE COT
 WHERE COT.CONFIGURABLEOBJECTTYPEID IN (SELECT CIO.DAMAGEDCOTEMPLATE
                                          FROM CLAIMINSURANCEOBJECT CIO
                                    INNER JOIN CLAIMRISKUNIT CRU ON CRU.CLAIMRISKUNITID = CIO.CLAIMRISKUNITID
                                    INNER JOIN CLAIM CL ON CL.CLAIMID = CRU.CLAIMID
                                    INNER JOIN AGREGATEDPOLICY APO ON CL.POLICYID = APO.AGREGATEDPOLICYID))
```

OUTPUT:

```
RecSuiVidaCol,
RecSuiSegMigranteVida,
RecEnfSegMigranteVida,
RecAccPasajeroSeguro,
RecAgrSaldosDeudores,
RecEnfPasajeroSeguro,
RecAccSegMigranteVida,
RecAccVidaCol,
```

(All of the above are DB Tables again)

Now My second Query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE PK IN (SELECT CIO.DAMAGEDCOID
                                          FROM CLAIMINSURANCEOBJECT CIO
                                    INNER JOIN CLAIMRISKUNIT CRU ON CRU.CLAIMRISKUNITID = CIO.CLAIMRISKUNITID
                                    INNER JOIN CLAIM CL ON CL.CLAIMID = CRU.CLAIMID
                                    INNER JOIN AGREGATEDPOLICY APO ON CL.POLICYID = APO.AGREGATEDPOLICYID);
```

Field PK is not identified here.
I want all the fields as output from the table based on the condition

Comment: Please find a better title for your question. The SQL client you are using is completely irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

A CTE ( `with` clause ), perhaps?

```
WITH XYZ
AS (
    SELECT 'Ayub' as Name
    FROM Dual
    )
SELECT *
FROM XYZ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is for SQL*Plus. It may work in SQL Developer, as that tends to do a good job of emulating SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> column testname new_value testname

SQL> select 'user_sequences' as testname from dual;
old   1: select count(*) from &testname
new   1: select count(*) from user_sequences

TESTNAME
--------------
user_sequences

1 row selected.

SQL> select count(*) from &testname;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         4

1 row selected.

SQL> define testname
DEFINE TESTNAME        = "user_sequences" (CHAR)
```

Notes:

The `old` and `new` values are displayed because I [`set verify on`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_five.htm#SQPUG438).

The `new_value` option is part of the [`column` command](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve013.htm#SQPUG034).